# How to close a Ruby Heredoc with string-interpolated identifier

Tags: ruby, syntax, heredoc

Within the context of IRB, I'm exploring Ruby's Heredoc functionality and attempted to use string interpolation inside the **identifier**, *not* inside the Heredoc itself. The problem is that when I try to close the Heredoc, I am unable to do so and must CTRL+D to force quit.

No matter what I type to close the Heredoc, IRB thinks I am still typing new lines inside the Heredoc.

```
irb(main):001:0> identifier = "EOF"
irb(main):002:0> <<"#{identifier}"
irb(main):003:0" "#{identifier}"
irb(main):004:0" #{identifier}
irb(main):005:0" "EOF"
irb(main):006:0" EOF
irb(main):007:0"
```

Is it possible to close this Heredoc, and if so, what is IRB expecting?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: If you immediately close a HEREDOC in Ruby, it returns an empty string `""`. Here's [the test for this behavior](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/c5eb24349a4535948514fe765c3ddb0628d81004/spec/ruby/language/heredoc_spec.rb#L67)

Comment: I would guess this is due to the parser in IRB, which can get a bit confused at times. For what it’s worth, it seems to work in Pry and a normal script.